# Parsing the Django model results

Tags: python, django, django-models

i have a problem in parsing the model results. i have a model with some of data in it. with this method i run a query on that table:

```
def get_result(request):
   res = Myapp.objects.filter(state=1)
   return HttpResponse(res)
```

it works but return this response:

```
Myapp object Myapp object
```

according to my PHP base experience, i was thinking that res variable is an array or a python list etc... but i cant parse it! how i can extract the fields in each result object?
for example i was thinking this should have to work:

```
return HttpResponse(res[0]["name"])
```

but it doesn't! and i get this error:

```
'Myapp' object has no attribute '__getitem__'
```

where is the problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The result of the query on your database is a [QuerySet](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/querysets/). You use the dot notation to access the fields in your model:

```
res[i].name
```